# Running iperf in bidirectional mode goes slower than unidirectional

Tags: linux, networking, performance

I used iperf to test throughput on box A and B, both 1Gbps NIC.

I found:

- A->B can reach 940 Mbps
- B->A can reach 940 Mbps

But with `iperf -d`, to test bidirectional transfers, the result is
only about 670 Mbps, so what can cause this problem? Switch or router?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two hosts connected through a 1Gbps, full-duplex link, and
you find that unidirectional transfers get close to 1000Mbps, but
bidirectional transfers go down to less than 70% of the theoretical
maximum. There could be several causes, including:

- the network equipment, such as switches, in between the two hosts,
  which may be limited to less than 2Gbps of total in+out throughput;
- your host's CPU being overloaded from having to process this much
  data;
- your network interfaces being less than perfect.